# Wordpress Role Display Name

Tags: wordpress, roles

I am looking for a neat way to get the Wordpress role display name.

When you **add the role** (e.g. `add_role( 'special', 'A Special Role');` ), you get to set a display name.

When you **get the role** (e.g. `get_role( 'special' );` ) the role object returned simply has the name and the capabilities object.

```
WP_Role Object(
[name] => special
[capabilities] => Array() )
```

And **no** display name. The display name is used all over the WP Admin back-end (users.php and user-edit.php), but it's a rabbit warren ... and I haven't been able to find a function that will return it. You can readily see it in the `wp_user_roles` row in the `wp-options` table - surely I don't need to go there?

Answer (score 12):

If you are running a non-english WordPress site and want to display the proper (translated) Role name, as it appears in all WordPress administration pages, here's how to do it:

```
    global $wp_roles;
    echo translate_user_role( $wp_roles->roles[ $role ]['name'] );
```

where `$role` is the role name (i.e. `'special'` in the original question).

Note: [translate_user_role](http://wpseek.com/translate_user_role/) is a WordPress core not-so-documented function.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution to the above scenario:

```
    global $wp_roles;
    $role = $wp_roles->roles['special']['name'];
```

Or in my case, what I was trying to achieve was:

```
    global $wp_roles;
    $u = get_userdata($user->ID);
    $role = array_shift($u->roles);
    $user->role = $wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'];
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

if ($user_role == 'administrator') {
echo 'Administrator';
} elseif ($user_role == 'editor') {
echo 'Editor';
} elseif ($user_role == 'author') {
echo 'Author';
} elseif ($user_role == 'contributor') {
echo 'Contributor';
} elseif ($user_role == 'subscriber') {
echo 'Subscriber';
} else {
echo '<strong>' . $user_role . '</strong>';
}
?>
```