# How can I get the role name by the role id in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How the hell can I get the role name by the given role id in WordPress? I've searched in the whole network but I can't find any useful answer. So I've this code here which returns me the role_id of a role:

```
$user['user']->roles[0]
```

So this returns `um_customer` for example. The name of the role is `Customer` and this is what I need.

Comment: See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059638/wordpress-role-display-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26187405/2540235)

```
global $wp_roles;
echo translate_user_role( $wp_roles->roles[ $role ]['name'] );
```

But, I want to point out that you are confused about the difference between the role's "name" and "id" -- in fact, your posted code DOES display the "name" of the role (which may explain why you've had so much trouble finding an answer).

Really, you are looking for the **Display Name** of the role, which is displayed using the code above (and is not well documented by Wordpress).

Answer (score 1):

If you put the role id into a variable, you can match it looping through the WordPress role object.

Try something like:

```
$role_id = $user['user']->roles[0];
$get_all_roles = $wp_roles->roles;

foreach ( $get_all_roles as $k => $v ) {
  if ( $k == $role_id ) {
    $role_name = $v['name'];
  }
}
```

Let me know if it does the job ;)

Comment: With adding global $wp_roles; it works also great. But I like the one line solution above :) but thanks for trying to help!